# How do I push List or Map type to DynamoDB with the .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to push some data into an DynamoDB table and I'm having trouble making the .NET SDK detect that I want a List or Map type, rather than the Numbered/String Set types.

```
 var doc = new Document();
 doc["Game ID"] = "SW Proto";
 doc["Run ID"] = 666;
 doc["Profiler Column"] = stats.Key.ToString();
 //doc["Stats Data"] = stats.Value as List<string>;
 // Works:
 doc["Stats Data"] = new List<string> { "2.45", "2.35", "2.5" };
 // Fails:
 doc["Stats Data"] = new List<string> { "2.45", "2.45", "2.45" };
```

It fails because the data is non-unique, as required for a Set type.

How does one force the data to serialize to List or Map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To store a list (L) instead of a string set (SS), you need to use a different conversion schema. [This blog post](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx2TCOGWG7ARUH5/DynamoDB-Series-Conversion-Schemas) discusses the different conversion schemas and how they can be used.